# How to sort class members in existing code in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I worked in Eclipse before, but IDEA seems more comfortable for me.

I want to press some hotkey to order all source members.

There's an option: Project settings - Code Style - Java - Code Generation - Order of members.
But it doesn't work with an existing code.

How can I sort them by category (like Static Inner Classes, then Inner Classes, then Static fields etc...) and alphabetically in each category?

Is there a possibility to do this in IDEA? May be, with some plugin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In IDEA 11 you can use [Rearranger](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=173) plug-in, IDEA 12 [will support it out of the box](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-intellij-idea-12/).